# How to add CSS code to make responsive for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, css

I have android program that use view web server local HTML. But HTML don't work well in android device emulator. I use these CSS codes but it doesn't work.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {}   
@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 0.75) {}
```

And these below CSS codes, it work for browsers but it doesn't work well for android emulator.

```
@media screen and (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1200px){}
@media screen and (min-width:720px) and (max-width:959px) {}
@media screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:719px) {}
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:639px) {}
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:479px) {}
```

Could someone tell me the CSS codes that work for phones and tablet, landscape and portrait. Thanks for answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version should work seamlessly:

```
@media screen and (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1200px){}
@media screen and (min-width:720px) and (max-width:959px) {}
@media screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:719px) {}
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:639px) {}
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:479px) {}
```

Because the first version relies on device pixel ratio not upon the actual screen sizes. Did you insert the [viewport meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) in the `head`?

Comment: Thanks I forget metatag use in `head`. I used outside.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem, however if you're having the problem I think you are: try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this in head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

and in css file write media query as follows.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
}
```